# Best Way to Optimize this Largest Prime Factor Program

Tags: java, optimization, timeout, prime-factoring

I need some help optimizing this program. I am trying to figure out the largest prime factor for input. However, it occasionally has timeout issues, so I am interested in figuring out how to optimize it.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.math.*;
import java.util.regex.*;

public class PFactor() {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int t = in.nextInt();
        
        for(int a0 = 0; a0 < t; a0++){
            long n = in.nextLong();
            System.out.println(pMod(n));
        }
    }

    public static int pMod(long d) {
        long maxVal = 0;
        
        for (long i = 2; i <= d; i++) {
            if (d % i == 0) {
                boolean prime = pCount(i);
                if (prime == true) {
                    max = i;
                }
            } else {                
                max = max;
            }
        }
        return (int)max;
    }
    
    public static boolean pCount(long inLong) {
        int count = 0;
        for (long s = 1; s <= inLong; s++) {
            if (inLong % s == 0) {
                count++;
            } 
        }
        
        if (count == 2) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Do you know how to optimize this code so that it does not have as many timeouts? I need this ready soon for something at work, so I decided to reach out to see if I could get some help, as I can't seem to figure it out myself where it needs further optimization.

Comment: Sorry about some of my grammar. English is not my first language, and I can't help it.

Comment: You might start by not recomputing whether each value is prime every time through, only testing odd divisors, and dividing out known factors so you can bail out sooner.

Comment: How'd I do that? Can you post what modifications you would do so I could see what ya mean?

Comment: Start by implementing a [sieve](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes)

Comment: I'm a Visual Learner, so I usually need you to post edited versions of the original code so I can see it in action.

Comment: Well, the `else { max = max; }` line is pointless, right?  And don't compare things to `true` or `false`. They already are.

Answer (score 0):

I actuallly found a solution guys after a bit of tinkering with it! you were all very helpful though! Thanks for helping!